# How can you print a variable in quotation marks?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
favoriteword = input('Enter your word: ')
print('What is your favorite word?',favoriteword)
print(favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword,favoriteword)
print(favoriteword, 'does not even sound like a word anymore.')
```

How can I make it so that in line 4 it comes out as "___" does not even sound like a word anymore." If I put it as this below it doesn't work.

```
print('"favoriteword"', 'does not even sound like a word anymore.')
```

Also if I put line 2 into a loop how would I print it so that it prints on a single line?

```
for i in range(12):
    print(favoriteword)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or above, you can use [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print('"{}" does not even sound like a word anymore.'.format(favoriteword))
```

In lower versions, Ketzak's method will work.

---

To print multiple times on a single line, you want to prevent `print` from appending a newline.

In Python 3, use the `end` argument:

```
for i in range(12):
    print(favoriteword, end='')
print('')  # for newline
```

or in lower versions:

```
import sys

for i in range(12):
    sys.stdout.write(favoriteword)
print('')
```

Comment: This method is actually better, as it is more reliable, and functions the same across Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Appreciate it! Any clue about how I could change the print for the for-loop to print as a single line rather than 12 lines?

Comment: Beat me to it. Lol. Worst part of trying to answer and gain rep is people faster than you.

Comment: Bear in mind that that loop will not print a newline at the end, so you may want to explicitly do that. You could also `print(" ".join([favoriteword] *12)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the Python interpolation operator if you can guarantee `favoriteword` will always be a string:

`print('"%s" does not even sound like a word anymore.' % favoriteword)`

Answer (score 2):

In python >= 3.6, you can use "f-string":

`print(f'"{favoriteword}" does not even sound like a word anymore.')`

See [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) for more information about it.